# Menu items testing selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am making a test script, during which all menu items must be clicked. If items have nested submenus, they also must be clicked. I understand that I need to do something through the "if". If there is a submenu, then run a function that will go through them, if there are none, then repeat the current one, but I don’t know java very well and don’t understand how to implement it. Now my functions are simply driven in a circle through one menu item and its submenus. Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#box-apps-menu li a"));
       int numberOfMenuElements = elementList.size();
       for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMenuElements; i++) {
           elementList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#box-apps-menu li a"));
           elementList.get(i).click();
           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("h1")));

           List<WebElement> subMenuElementsList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".docs>li"));
           int numberOfsubMenuElements = subMenuElementsList.size();
           for (int j = 0; j < numberOfsubMenuElements; j++) {
               subMenuElementsList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".docs>li"));
               subMenuElementsList.get(j).click();
               wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("h1")));
           }

       }
```

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: https://demo.litecart.net/admin/
side menu

Answer (score 0):

I had to get menu items after every DOM change and collect already clicked links. There it is:

```
package selenium;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Sasha extends WebDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // wrapped driver initialization
        driver.get("https://demo.litecart.net/admin/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"box-login\"]/form/div[2]/button")).click();
        List<String> clickedLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<WebElement> links = getLinks();
        for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
            List<WebElement> links2 = getLinks();
            WebElement link = links2.get(i);
            String href = link.getAttribute("href");
            if (!clickedLinks.contains(href)) {
                link.click();
                printHeader();
                clickedLinks.add(href);
                List<WebElement> links3 = getLinks();
                for (int j = 0; j < links3.size(); j++) {
                    List<WebElement> links4 = getLinks();
                    WebElement link2 = links4.get(j);
                    String href2 = link2.getAttribute("href");
                    if (!clickedLinks.contains(href2)) {
                        link2.click();
                        printHeader();
                        clickedLinks.add(href2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static List<WebElement> getLinks() {
        WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.id("box-apps-menu"));
        return box.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    }
    
    public static void printHeader() {
        if (driver.findElements(By.className("panel-heading")).size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.className("panel-heading")).getText());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("content")).getText());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-refs/branch-heads/4664@{#947}) on port 44763
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Lis 25, 2021 9:58:04 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Template
Logotype
Edit Styling
Catalog
Suppliers
Delivery Statuses
Sold-Out Statuses
Quantity Units
CSV Import/Export
Countries
Settings – Store Info
Settings – Defaults
Settings – Email
Settings – Listings
Settings – Customer Details
Settings – Legal
Settings – Images
Settings – Checkout
Currencies
Customers
CSV Import/Export
Newsletter Recipients
Geo Zones
Pages
CSV Import/Export
Monthly Sales
Most Shopping Customers
Slides
Not available in demo
Languages
Storage Encoding
Customer Modules
Payment Modules
Order Modules
Order Total Modules
Job Modules
Orders
Tax Rates
Search Translations
CSV Import/Export
Users
```